# Continuous morlet wavelet transform using pywt

Tags: python, wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I am using `pywavelets` to perform `CWT` on my data, `fs = 256Hz`, length of the signal is `1024`. 
why does it say `invalid wavelet name` ?

I tried to perform using `haar wavelet`, then it worked but I am not sure i have got correct signal.

this is what i tried,

```
w = pywt.Wavelet('haar')
scaling, wavelet, x = w.wavefun(level=10)
```

[image]

Inputs on solving this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried (= share your code). Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].